How to export Azure Cosmos MongoDB & Collection properties
Is there any way to export details  of all existing  azure cosmos mongo databases, its RU value & scaling properties, and the details of collection belongs to each database in that list  with its properties in a table format ?
Looking for a way, that can be automated using azuredevops pipeline, where we can give the cosmos db instance as list. it should be capable to fetch DB and collection properties dynamically.

Please edit your question to show your work and what specific issue(s) you are running  (a [mcve]). Right now you only posted a set of requirements. Seems like most (if not all) of what you want should be attainable via cli / powershell.
